# Why does certain @font-face not work in IE

Tags: css

Is there any reason why the last 2 fonts shouldn't work in IE. They all work in chrome and FF. And the first 2 work in IE. What causes this?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Bebasneue";
    src: url('bebasneue.eot?') format('eot'), url('bebasneue.woff') format('woff'), url('bebasneue.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "corbel";
    src: url('corbel.eot?') format('eot'), url('corbel.woff') format('woff'), url('corbel.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "LeagueGothic";
    src: url('LeagueGothic-Regular.eot?') format('eot'), url('LeagueGothic-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('LeagueGothic-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    src: url('Lobster_1.eot?') format('eot'), url('Lobster_1.woff') format('woff'), url('Lobster_1.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: It could be the fonts themselves that are misbehaving. I have experienced corrupt EOT files in the past. You could try converting them again, using a service such as the Font Squirrel generator (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

Comment: which version of ie? if it is less than 9 you may need something like this: `src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')`

Answer (score 0):

I would try running all your fonts through the font-squirrel font-face generator linked below:

It is incredibly useful for generating cross browser css and fixes the pesky IE issues!

[Font squirrel font face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)